# Android app performance meter automation

Tags: android, performance, automation

Is there a way to automatically test android apps performance, like the time, needed by an app to load itself and become ready for user's interaction in android?

Comment: Eclipse - Memory Analysis Tool commonly known as the [MAT](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one useful thing to do app performance automation is `dumpsys` that is described in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qfo5fdoXrTU

[image]

Also there is a nice log output for the app start time, this is a quote from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html):

> From Android 4.4 (API level 19), logcat includes an output line
>   containing a value called Displayed. This value represents the amount
>   of time elapsed between launching the process and finishing drawing
>   the corresponding activity on the screen. The elapsed time encompasses
>   the following sequence of events:
>
> Launch the process. Initialize the objects. Create and initialize the
>   activity. Inflate the layout. Draw your application for the first
>   time. The reported log line looks similar to the following example:
>
> ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming:
>   +3s534ms